# importing a picture using imread

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, imread

i'm  trying to run this code in a jupyter notebook but i'm getting an error:

```
from matplotlib.image import imread
test = imread("data/photo1.jpg")
print(type(test))
```

error:

```
   1411         try:
-> 1412             from PIL import Image
   1413         except ImportError:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
```

Does anyone know why I'm getting this? I'm importing imread, so no idea where PIL comes into it.

Thanks.

Comment: I found the mistake. imread can only handle png's by default. After installing "pillow", I was able to handle the jpg using the above code! Hope this post helps someone else encountering the same issue!

Comment: You can also make this an answer an accept it.

Comment: Wasn't sure how to do this (accept a comment as an answer), so I posted a new answer and accepted it.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant... write it as a new answer and accept it.  This way other people know it's solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the mistake. imread can only handle png's by default. After installing "pillow", I was able to handle the jpg using the above code! Hope this post helps someone else encountering the same issue!